# Bind User Control to view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am still getting my head around MvvM so please bear with me.

I have a simple User Control called DatePickerUC

```
partial class DatePickerUC
    {
...........
 private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dateTimePicker2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

I now need to load this user control into my ViewModel and then reference it from my XAML code so that the user control containing the 2 date pickers and button load at runtime.

But not sure how to go about it

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Windows Form controls in a WPF usercontrol? Is it really required?

Comment: You don't "load" or reference Views into the ViewModel. ViewModel has to be agnostic (unaware) of ANY UI/View

Answer (score 0):

In general, you really shouldn't be doing this. *Especially* with WinForms controls.

However, `Content` is a dependency property, so it *can* be bound. You can write this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
```

If `CurrentView` is a property that returns that user control, it will work fine. Its complicated by the fact that you have **WinForms** controls, you'll need a WPF WindowsFormsHost wrapper around those controls for it to work.

Comment: Used BooleanToVisibilityConverter instead. Told you I was new to this thanks for the reply though

Comment: @Ross One thing to caution about that, it gets awfully messy if you have lots of these. Glad you got a solution!